# Rails serializers - Controlling attributes of the association using selective include / exclude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have 2 resources - `post` and `author`. `post` has an `author`. When I fetch the post details, I would like to selectively include the details of the author.

Example -

`GET /authors/1`

```
{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'Some name',
  'email': 'admin@example.com',
  'address': 'Some address',
  'mobile': '',
  'language': 'ruby'
}
```

`GET /posts/1`

I would like to have -

```
{
  'id': 1,
  'created_at': '2017-01-01 10:00:00',
  'views': 7500,
  'seo_score': 4,
  'author': {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Some name',
    'email': 'admin@example.com'
  }
}
```

instead of,

```
{
  'id': 1,
  'created_at': '2017-01-01 10:00:00',
  'views': 7500,
  'seo_score': 4,
  'author': {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Some name',
    'email': 'admin@example.com',
    'address': 'Some address',
    'mobile': '',
    'language': 'ruby'
  }
}
```

- I would like to know if I can selectively choose the attributes of the association in the serializers, by using `include`, `exclude`, `only` etc.
- I know I can write a separate serializer and map it to the association while defining it, but just to include 2 specific attributes I don't think adding a separate class makes sense.
- I also know that I can override the association and fetch all the attributes and selectively choose a few; but I would like to know if Serializers support this by default.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new association with your selected columns like this

```
belongs_to :author_with_partial_details, -> { select [:id, :name, :email] }, :class_name => "Author"
```

and use it something like this

```
Post.find(params[:id]).includes(:author_with_partial_details)
```

Alternatively you can also use jbuilder gem to create your own JSON structure, here is the link to the gem https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: Thanks, will check and respond back.

Comment: I would like to know how to use it in serializers to output the json. This answer shows the same thing, but using models and controllers.

Comment: this is a good read to learn how to use serializers and json response https://www.sitepoint.com/active-model-serializers-rails-and-json-oh-my/